# Strange error "match(regexp: string | RegExp): ?Array<string>;" in core.js ruuning Flow v0.52

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

When running flow v0.52 the following error is shown:

```
node_modules\.bin\flow check --show-all-errors
Library type error:
C:\temp\flow\flowlib_20ad61e3\core.js:304
304:     match(regexp: string | RegExp): ?Array<string>;
                                                ^^^^^^ string. The operand of an arithmetic operation must be a number.

Found 1 error
```

Is this an internal flow problem or if not, how can I track this kind of error down?

os: windows 7 x64
node: 8.3.0
npm: 5.3.0
flow: 0.52.0

Comment: Are you using `string.match` anywhere in your codebase? The error is suggesting that it's being used somewhere, and the output is being used in an arithmetic operation. ex:  `'string'.match('5') - 3`

Comment: @RossSolomon Thank for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually an error in the application code itself and only the error message was wrong.

The following setting in `.flowconfig`:

```
[options]
traces=10
```

gave me the exact location of the error.